# Select average from MySQL table with LIMIT

Tags: sql, mysql, average

I am trying to get the average of the lowest 5 priced items, grouped by the username attached to them.  However, the below query gives the average price for each user (which of course is the price), but I just want one answer returned.

```
SELECT AVG(price) 
  FROM table 
 WHERE price > '0' && item_id = '$id' 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY price ASC 
   LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give an example  table structure, some example data and the expected result for that data?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT AVG(items.price)
  FROM (SELECT t.price
          FROM TABLE t
         WHERE t.price > '0' 
           AND t.item_id = '$id'
      ORDER BY t.price
         LIMIT 5) items
```

It will return the average of the 5 lowest prices - a single answer.

Comment: Congrats on reaching 160K+ rep!!

Comment: Congrats on reaching 201k+ rep!

Comment: Congrats on reaching 224k+ rep!

Comment: Congrats on reaching 265k+ rep!

Comment: Congrats on reaching 300k+ rep!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution below.

**Query:**

```
SELECT  AVG(Column_name) 
FROM  (SELECT Column_name 
FROM  Table
WHERE  ColumnID < number[Limit you want] ) alias
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias