# Find average account balance for each branch

Tags: mysql

If I have a table with the columns:

```
branch-name
account-balance
```

Assuming there are more than one entries for branch-name and account-balance, how can I perform a query to show the average account balance for each branch-name?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select average from MySQL table with LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854383/select-average-from-mysql-table-with-limit)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT avg(account-balance) AS branchAverage, branch-name
FROM tableName
GROUP BY branch-name
```

Answer (score -2):

select branch_name from Account group by branch_name having avg(balance) >= all( select avg(balance) from Account group by branch_name);