# Selecting a Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been bugging this for the past hour..

I want to get the TOP 5 from latest data from my table `clickednumbers`

`clickednumbers` has only to columns `numbers` as INT &  `numberTime` as timestamp

My query

```
SELECT AVG( SELECT *
            FROM clickednumbers
            ORDER BY numberTime DESC
            LIMIT 5)
FROM clickednumbers
```

and im always getting the error

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntanx to use near
'SELECT * 
 FROM clicked numbers
 ORDER BY numberTime DESC '
at line 1`

`MariaDB Version:Server type: MariaDB
                Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
                Protocol version: 10`

Sorry for bothering :(

Goal : To get the average of top 5 from latest numbers based on the numbersTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the average of the top 5, use a subquery in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT AVG(numbers)
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM clickednumbers
      ORDER BY numberTime DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) cn;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854383/select-average-from-mysql-table-with-limit) for more of an idea what's going on. I think your query needs to look more like this:

```
SELECT AVG(x.numbers) 
  FROM (SELECT numbers FROM clickednumbers ORDER BY numberTime DESC
  LIMIT 5) as x
```